# Beautify Yii URLs

Tags: php, url, yii, user-friendly

I have URL like below:

```
hbbh/object/category/id/4/name/category_name/gId/3/group/group_name
```

And I want to change it to something like below:

```
hbbh/object/category/category_name/group_name
```

Also I added below rule to `urlManager` rules:

```
'<_c:(object|auction)>/<_a:(category)>/<name:\w+>/<group:\w+>' => '<_c>/<_a>',
```

The URL generated after these codes is:

```
hbbh/object/category/digital_suplies/mobile?id=2&gId=20
```

Now is there anyway to remove `?id=2&gId=20` at the end of URL?
Any suggestion will be apreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: Simply do not put these into `createUrl()`. With this however, you have a problem getting category and group ID. It's very common just to append IDs to the string `hbbh/object/category/digital_suplies-2/mobile-20`.

Comment: @chris thanks,  if I keep on with your solution,  do I have SEO?

Comment: I'm no seo expert so I cannot tell you if this would be good sorry. But with Yii it is very easy to change your urls. Just do a little research on seo.

Comment: I search for it over and over but didn't find complete refrence.  So if you know anywhere please guide me.  Thank again

Comment: There is no wrong or right here, this is better than that. It just depends. I cannot give you any more advice. Look how other big sites manage this url thing, they are probably doing it right, because they have researched a lot. So it can't be that bad to do it the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't such appropriate capability. The best way is format it, to be sound good.
for example we can change it to this format:

```
hbbh/object/category/digital_suplies-2/mobile-20
```

By changing urlManager as below:

```
'<_c:(object|auction)>/<_a:(category)>/<name:\w+>-<cid:\d+>/
                       <group:\w+>-<gid:\d+>' => '<_c>/<_a>',
```